# Criar função para formatação de (X-1, X-2, X-3) para ('X-1', 'X-2', 'X-3')

Tags: mysql, create, funções

Tenho uma query que retorna algumas chaves tipo CHAR como essa `X-1, X-2, X-3`. O problema é que agora preciso usar com `where chaves in( ... )` e teria que formatar os valores para 
`'X-1', 'X-2', 'X-3'`. Isso me pouparia alguns relacionamentos...

Como esta tudo dentro da query, não posso formatar com PHP, então pensei em criar ma função no MYSQL para essa finalidade, mas não sei quais funções usaria.

`X-1, X-2, X-3` são chaves concatenadas com `group_concat` para jogar na clausula `in( ... )`, por esse motivo precisava formatar.

Comment: Acho que resolvi com a própria função usando parâmetros: `group_concat( '"' , chaves , '"' )` : `"X-1","X-2","X-3"`.

Comment: Não funcionou como esperado.